# TextEdit disables menu when selected text has different fonts/styles

Tags: textedit, formatting, sonoma

Prior to Sonoma, when using TextEdit (virtually always editing rich text docs), I could select any text and add/remove a style to whatever styles were present in the text.  For example, if I had a sentence: This is an example of **bold**, and I wanted to use *italics* for the whole sentence, I simply selected the whole sentence and clicked the *I* button. Simple, and common to most editors.

In Sonoma, however, if I select the wole sentence, the menu options become gray/disabled.  I am forced to first select the non-bold part, italicize it, then select the bold part, and italicize that.  Since I edit docs extensively, this requires a LOT of extra time.

I've searched haven't found anyone else mentioning this change, so I'm wondering if it is specific to my machine?  Or some setting I'm missing?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Works for me as far as I can tell, but it would depend if the particular typeface has an italic style - what fonts are you using?

Comment: I'm using Helvetica.  If I bold or italicize a word in a sentence, then select the whole sentence, the menu is disabled. If I underline a word then select the whole sentence, the menu stays enabled. so the issue seems to target certain styles. I tried Arial with the same results.  Selecting a sentence with mixed styles (some combination of regular, bold, and/or italics) disables the styles parts of the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the same behaviour on macOS 14.2.1, TextEdit 1.19 (404), it seems to be a bug.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. If the format is not already in rich text, from the menu:

   Format -> Make Rich Text
2. Type "abc def ghi"
3. Set "def" in bold
4. Select all the text

**Observed behavior**

The buttons "B" and "I" are greyed out.

**Desired behavior**

The buttons "B" and "I" should not be greyed out. Clicking on them should have the same behavior as hitting  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>B</kbd>  and  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>I</kbd> , i.e. applying the style on all selected text.

[image]

**Workaround**

There is a simple workaround. When the menu options are disabled, you can simply use the shortcuts  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>B</kbd>  and  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>I</kbd> . They work as intended.

**Reproduced on:**

- macOS 14.2.1, TextEdit 1.19 (404)
- macOS 14.3, TextEdit 1.19 (404)
- macOS 14.3.1, TextEdit 1.19 (404)
- macOS 14.4, TextEdit 1.19 (404)
- macOS 14.4.1, TextEdit 1.19 (404)

Comment: You should send your reportage to [Apple Product Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).

Comment: Thank you, Ortomala, for verifying, and the suggested work-around which works for me as well.  I have reported the issue to Apple Product Feedback (to the MacOs category as they don't have a category specific to TextEdit) as suggested by IconDaemon.